# How to debug EOFError raised from Devise actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have started getting a strange issue in a Rails app, that is proving very difficult to debug.

```
EOFError
end of file reached
```

is being raised on some Devise routes. So far I'm getting this on `session#destroy` and `registration#update` (I have not been able to try others).

The issue is not occurring in tests, only in development environment.

After stepping through the controllers, the error appears to be raised on the following lines.

```
registration#update
resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)

session#destroy
signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
```

I realise that identifing the cause will likely need much more code. But after several hours trying to debug this I'm at a loss to next steps. I'd be grateful if anyone can:

1. Suggest how to obtain more useful information when `EOFError` is
   raised. Currently all I'm getting is `Completed 500 Internal Server
   Error in 2627ms (ActiveRecord: 10.1ms) EOFError - end of file
   reached:` without much to identify where this is being raised.
2. Suggest a logical approach to debug this. From my attempts, the
   error appears to be coming from the Devise internals, which I don't
   think is correct.

Comment: maybe the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819801/rails-eoferror-end-of-file-reached-when-saving-a-devise-user/16827336) question can help to get yours. Also for debugging errors, I use [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors). You may it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Roshan this is a useful reference, but I don't think it solves my problem. I've just replaced my entire initializer with the default - I am using Devise::Mailer and have set mail_sender to mailer@example.com. I'm still getting the error. Have I missed something?